# javascript traverse json object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, object

I always think it's going to be easy... I plan to use the json below to build router objects. I put a console.log and so I could have a break point spot so I could try to figure out how to access the the object properties from the chrome console.  It never goes into the for loop though.

The main question is how to properly turn the JSON into objects and how to access it's properties.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON('JSON/data.json', function(json) {

            for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
                console.log("in for loop");
            }

        });
    });

</script>





{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "4f91f2c9e4b0d0a881cf86c4"
},
"DSC21": {
    "Router": {
        "online": [
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ],
        "bytes": [
            "59.5721304971465",
            "17014.1911069063",
            "14858.8518936735",
            "6875.20981475265",
            "15157.6891384625",
            "6363.47544785913",
            "29446.2111270486",
            "11517.9296243171",
            "27077.9747917112",
            "19867.79381695"
        ]
    }
},
"DSC22": {
    "Router": {
        "online": [
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ],
        "bytes": [
            "59.5721304971465",
            "17014.1911069063",
            "14858.8518936735",
            "6875.20981475265",
            "15157.6891384625",
            "6363.47544785913",
            "29446.2111270486",
            "11517.9296243171",
            "27077.9747917112",
            "19867.79381695"
        ]
    }
},
"DSC23": {
    "Router": {
        "online": [
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ],
        "bytes": [
            "59.5721304971465",
            "17014.1911069063",
            "14858.8518936735",
            "6875.20981475265",
            "15157.6891384625",
            "6363.47544785913",
            "29446.2111270486",
            "11517.9296243171",
            "27077.9747917112",
            "19867.79381695"
        ]
    }
},
"DSC24": {
    "Router": {
        "online": [
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1",
            "1"
        ],
        "bytes": [
            "59.5721304971465",
            "17014.1911069063",
            "14858.8518936735",
            "6875.20981475265",
            "15157.6891384625",
            "6363.47544785913",
            "29446.2111270486",
            "11517.9296243171",
            "27077.9747917112",
            "19867.79381695"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Check this: `$.getJSON('JSON/data.json', function(json) {console.log(json); ...}`

Comment: @gdoron the console remained blank

Comment: Please read some [introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn how to work with objects and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is natively available in JavaScript, you traverse it like you would traverse any object or array.

```
json["DSC21"]["Router"]["online"][0];    // 1
json.DSC21.Router.online[0];    // equivalent
json.DSC21.Router.online.0;    // INCORRECT
```

If you don't know the names of the properties and want to loop through them use the `for .. in` construction:

```
for (var key in json) {
    console.log(key);   // _id, DSC21, DCS22 etc..
    console.log(json[key]);    // { "$oid": "" }, { "Router": ".." } etc.
}
```

This does leave the `hasOwnProperty` issue, but it shouldn't be a problem if you're just reading JSON data.

Comment: *"JSON is natively available in JavaScript"* What does that mean? A JSON **parser** is natively available in JavaScript (since ES5) which converts JSON to objects/arrays, that's all.

Comment: What if there are nested objects and strings inside how can you implement this solution in that specific case?

Comment: @xeeB Can you post your data structure and which properties you want to read?

Answer (score 4):

The variable `json` is already an object, but it is not an array, so a typical for-loop is insufficient.  Since `json.length` is undefined, `i<json.length` fails on the first iteration and you skip over the loop.

```
for (var key in json) {
    // key is your DSCxxx
    // json[key] is the corresponding object
}
```

Comment: Ahhh so it's an array of objects.

Comment: You might want to see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261753/javascript-traverse-json-object#comment13193969_10261753) of the OP...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you want to know how to iterate your objects?

here would be how to do that:

```
for( var key in json ){
   if( key != '_id'){
      var router = json[key].Router;
      for( var i = 0; i < router.online.length; i++ ){
        console.log(i + ' is online: ', router.online[i]==1?'true':'false');
      }
      etc...
   }
}
```