# form validation using json structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, validation

I have several forms on a single page. One button click triggers all the form submissions (default behavior of my enterprise application).
I need to validate all the forms using jQuery before submission can be made. 
The form validations rules are in strored in a file in json format. The format is similar to the one that [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) uses.
I know it will be lot simpler to use the plugin but unfortunately I cannot use this plugin in my application.

I understand it will be a recursive code going through all the objects in json and then performing checks and use jquery to highlight the offending element but I am not sure how to start.

Is there any sample code available that illustrates on how to parse this json structure and highlight the elements that fail the check?

Any guidance on how to approach the solution will also help.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to parse json. You can perform AJAX request for reading your json from file and on response you will get already parsed json.

Comment: Have you checked the source code of JQuery Validate plugin ?

Comment: I am using getJSON to get the json object. Now I need to traverse this object and perfom different validations. I need to have sample code to actually traverse this json object.

Comment: You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261753/javascript-traverse-json-object

Comment: @berdem I am in process of doing that but it has not of code that is not required for my requirement. Example functions inside the json, remote validations and the whole nine yards. I just wanted to find if there is any example available to get started on parsing json object.